# Toolchain in openwrt?

Tags: gcc, g++, beagleboneblack, openwrt

I have installed `openwrt` on `beaglebone black`. I found out it doesn't have `gcc`, `g++` or any other compiler/toolchain.

How can i install compiler (preferable g++) for C and C++ in openwrt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openwrt doesn't have any compiler by default , because in many cases you have to compile software in cross compile environment.
So you can find the toolchain/gcc in "openwrt buildroot"
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build

But,
If you want to compile any source code on your Beaglebone , you can get it " opkg install gcc".

Comment: Do i need to add a mirror?

Comment: You need to edit /etc/opkg.conf and opkg update or input command "opkg install https://.......xx.ipk"

Comment: Can you provide some link to add in .conf file?

Comment: OK , I want to know your openWRT version

Comment: Yes, it is Linux OpenWrt 4.4.14. Bleeding Edge

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to find an AP with enough space to install gcc in it. The size of gcc_xxx.ipk is about 20MB. Check your free space in rootfs/overlay by typing `df -h`. If you have enough space modify your `/etc/opkg.conf` file with the following (modify Chaos Calmer for your OpenWrt version):

```
dest root /
dest ram /tmp
lists_dir ext /var/opkg-lists
option overlay_root /overlay
src/gz chaos_calmer_base http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/packages/base
src/gz chaos_calmer_packages http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages 
src/gz chaos_calmer_luci http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci              
src/gz chaos_calmer_routing http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/packages/routing    
src/gz chaos_calmer_telephony http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/packages/telephony
src/gz chaos_calmer_management http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/packages/management
```

If you don't have enough space you'll have to cross-compile your code.

Despite this you could install gcc in the `/tmp` memory that is usually much larger by typing

```
opkg update
opkg install gcc -d ram
```

and you will find gcc in `/tmp/usr/bin`. Remember that as soon as you reboot the router gcc will disappear and you will have to repeat all the process (if you install it on ram).